# como pasar variable a una función anónima javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

pues mi problema es que he creado una clase de javascript y en el constructor declaro algunas variables. 
pero en el metodo de SetImage la funcion anonima que usa el canvas para dibujar una imagen no funciona cuando le paso los parametros directamente como this._image y por eso las pase a nuevas variables como hago para que tome directamente el valor de this sin tener que volver a crear variables?

```
class TreeNode {
constructor(context, position, bgcolor = "#2196F3", dimensions = {w: 180, h: 50}) {
    this._context = context;
    this._position = position;
    this._dimensions = dimensions;
    this._bgcolor = bgcolor;

    this._context.fillStyle = "#2196F3";
    this._context.fillRect(this._position.x, this._position.y, this._dimensions.w, this._dimensions.h);

    this._image = new Image();
}

set SetImage(url) {
    var pos= this._position;
    var image = this._image;
    var context = this._context;
    this._image.src = url;
    this._image.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(image, pos.x, pos.y);
    };
}
```

}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tienes dos opciones. Una sería almacenar this en otra variable para poder utilizarla de manera interna, así:

```
var self = this;
this._image.src = url;
this._image.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(self._image, self._position.x, self._position.y);
};
```

La otra opción sería utilizar `bind` así:

```
this._image.src = url;
this._image.onload = (function () {
    context.drawImage(this._image, this._position.x, this._position.y);
}).bind(this);
```

> Esta última opción [no es compatible con Internet Explorer 8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5)

Comment: gracias si funciono estoy aprendiendo canvas y eso me estaba dando problemas